# Failed to download repository information, software & update useless

Tags: package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I know there's a lot of post with that same problem. But I can't seems to find one that help my case, so here we go. 
When I try to update via software updater I got the message « Failed to download repository ». My internet connection is fine. When I try by terminal does not work either, I think thoses lines illuminate the problem:

```
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu artful InRelease
Err:7 https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: AAC9264309E4D717441DB9527373B12CE03BEB4B
W: GPG error: https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: AAC9264309E4D717441DB9527373B12CE03BEB4B
E: The repository 'https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Also I'm not able to change anything from the software & update menu, I cannot check or uncheck any item..

I am really new to all this, please forgive my lack of ressourcefulness and thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: @karel I looked at that duplicate also, but the OP does not have the BADSIG error.  Will the process in the duplicate load the required key for the repository?

Answer (score 0):

I can't check this on my laptop, but your game' [site after click on Linux](https://www.runescape.com/download) recommends the following for installation on Linux:

```
sudo -s -- << EOF
wget -O - https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu/runescape.gpg.key | apt-key add -
mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y runescape-launcher
EOF
```

If you do not need this game anymore you can remove its APT *sources.list* file with

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```